# Hide ribbon items in Document Library

Tags: document-library, ribbon

I have created ribbon items using Quick Steps. Is it possible to display only Quick Steps items and hide remaining items in Document Library ribbon?

Comment: Do you want to hide all the default ribbon items and display only the custom actions u created?? Is it the question you meant ?

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Hide the Ribbon in SharePoint 2010 (Rajeswari Mohandas)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2012/04/30/how-to-hide-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-rajeswari-mohandas.aspx)